# Why is MySQL at 800% CPU or quitting?

Tags: 7, database

What would cause MySQL to suddenly run at almost 800% CPU or quit running? 
Our Drupal 7.50 site has started crashing recently.

First time the site went down, the website displayed this error to the public:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections in
>   _registry_check_code() (line 3462 of /var/www/html/example/docroot/includes/bootstrap.inc).

MySQL exceeded `max_connections` and I had to reboot the server because temporarily increasing from 151 to 500 still didn't help. I checked `top` and saw that MySQL was running at almost 800% CPU.

Restarting the VPS was the only thing that helped this.

[image]

[image]

The second time, the Drupal site only displayed a white page to the public, but the command `drush ws` produced the following error:

> Drush command shows: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function
>   module_exists() in
>   /usr/local/src/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment_7.inc on line
>   187

I confirmed with top that MySQL was not running. Records show that it was running at this same high CPU for several hours just before it stopped.

[image]

In this case, all I had to do was restart MySQL.

Is this a Drupal performance issue, traffic related, spam or something else? Any help is appreciated to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Possibly from a DDoS attack. **PS:** no need to take screenshots with your phone, use the Print Screen (Prt Scr) button in your keyboard.

Comment: Those are regular keyboard shortcut computer screenshots... no phone involved. How do I see if it was a DDoS attack?

Comment: @Christia SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'aborted_connects'; will display a count of connection attempts that have failed, since start of your instance. A rapidly growing count is a symptom of a DDoS attack.